# How to get actions from dynamically created button in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have create multiple button response with following , now how can  get the action from clicking on this button click

```
class ActionSearchCat(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_search_cat"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        buttons = []
        resp = requests.get('http://localhost:3001/api/categoryList/0')
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            # This means something went wrong.
            raise ApiError('GET /tasks/ {}'.format(resp.status_code))

        msg = resp.json().get('category_list').get('text')
        for list in resp.json().get('category_list').get('choices').items():
            for title, value in list.items():
                buttons.append({"title": title, "payload": "/"+value})

        dispatcher.utter_button_template(msg,buttons)
        return []
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, use `dispatcher.utter_button_message(msg, buttons)` instead of `utter_button_template`.

Now the buttons will be displayed on the channel to the end-user.  After they click one, the next message your AI assistant receives will have the intent `value` (the payload from the selected button).

You'll have to write a story to handle this intent.  If it is a unique intent to this button (i.e. you're not using something generic like `Yes` or `No` for your buttons) then the best approach would be to use the [`MappingPolicy`](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/#mapping-policy).  Either way, you'll also have to add the following story to your data as well:

```
## button_specific_action
* value
 - corresponding_action_for_value
```